# Android Studio Google Maps keep going back to user location when exploring map

Tags: android, google-maps

**Context:** I am working on an app that allows users to see other users in a 20 mile radius.  When they login they are sent to a MapsActivity that zooms to their current location and shows any other online users within 20 miles.

**Problem:** Every time I scroll around the map I get brought back to my current location and if I zoom out or in, it will zoom back into the same zoom I set it as.  I even tried this line but it didn't work:

`eaterGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);`

**What I need to happen:** Zoom to their location when they first open the MapsActivity in my App.  Allow the user to be able to scroll around the map just like in the Google Maps App and also update their position when they move, just like in Google Maps App.

**What I have done:**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


        // Constantly Update User location every 1.1 seconds!
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
            return;
        }

        Log.d("reque", "check here");
    }

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lastLocation = location;

    if (currentUserLocationMarker != null) {
        currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(getString(R.string.user_current_location_marker_title));
    markerOptions.visible(false);

    currentUserLocationMarker = eaterGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    float zoom = 17.0f;

    eaterGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    eaterGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    eaterGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    eaterGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

    // Begin to locate all online Vendors to display on map
    locateOnlineVendors();

}
```

Comment: onLocationChanged methode change location when you moved.  this method called  rapidly, and yo set zoom code inside this methode, that's while your zoom not working properly.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't set `eaterGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));` inside the `public void onConnected` method.  The zoom is set inside the `public void onLocationChanged` method.  If I understand you correctly.  What would I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag to control the zooming action.
Or only zoom in the `onConnect` (it means the first time)
By the way you don't have to remove your markers everytime, you can manipulate its position by `marker. setPosition(...)`

```
 boolean cameraSet = false;
 Marker marker;
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ...
    if(!cameraSet){
        eaterGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        cameraSet = true;
    }

 }
```

Comment: `if(!cameraSet){
        eaterGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        cameraSet = true;
    }` 

Works!  So clean and minimal, I love it.  Thank you.  I have had this issue for months but I put it off to focus on more core features.  This is one of the last things that needed to be fixed.  The boolean for cameraSet is false, then the if statement zooms in if the cameraSet is false making it true.  So if cameraSet is true, it will mean that the if statement stops running the zoom.  Such a simple solution, booleans are awesome, thank you!  Inspiring!

Answer (score 0):

set locationRequest smallest displacement to at least 1

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1);
```

No more booleans needed.